# File upload error with Qtnetworkaccessmanger 5.12

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I am trying to upload a json file to my server using **QtNetworkAccessManager**. But on the execution time of program gets error like connection closed or unknown error. Any one can help me to correct those error

```
upload = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(upload, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Cricbang::uploadFinished);
match_file=new QFile("saved/upcoming_match_list.json");
QFileInfo fileinfo(*match_file);
url.setUrl("http://serverIPadress/cricket/" +fileinfo.fileName() );
url.setUserName("userName");
url.setPassword("password");
url.setPort(22);
if (match_file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    rsult=upload->put(request, match_file);
}
```

upload function

```
 void Cricbang::uploadFinished(QNetworkReply* reply) {

   if (!reply->error()) {
       match_file->close();
       match_file->deleteLater();
       reply->deleteLater();
       QMessageBox::information(this, "upload", "finished");
   }
   else
   {
       QMessageBox::information(this, "error", reply->errorString());
   }
}
```